# passing parameter values to a stored procedure using csv file

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, csv, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure which has four parameters and i am inserting parameter values into four different tables

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Register]
  @pParameter1 VARCHAR(20)
 ,@pParameter2 VARCHAR(20)
 ,@pParameter3 VARCHAR(20)
 ,@pParameter4 VARCHAR(20)

  INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table1]
                       (Value1)
                 VALUES
                       (@pParameter1)

  INSERT INTO [dbo].[Table2]
                       (Value2)
                 VALUES
                       (@pParameter2) etc...
```

.csv file contains values for all the four parameters

My questions is

1. How to pass parameter values to the above stored procedure using values contained in .csv file ?

Technologies i am using are

1. ASP.NET - File upload control
2. C#
3. MS SQL Server 2012

Any help would be really appreciated

Comment: what did you try so far? please post some code.

Comment: I am new to this and i am trying to find a way wherein i can upload data in bulk using .csv files, was reading about BULK INSERT but i guess that it will not do the job for me as i need the user to select the .csv file from his end

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question:

> How to pass parameter values to the above stored procedure using values contained in .csv file ?

suggests to me that you haven't broken the problem down enough. To me, there are 2 entirely separate concerns here:

- how to parse a CSV file, preferably by row
- how to invoke SQL using parameters

The first can be done in many ways, but IIRC [CsvReader from code-project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9258/A-Fast-CSV-Reader) works quite well (other tools will probably work just as well). Then *per row*, simply add invoke the SQL with parameters via regular ADO.NET.